# Joomla 3.4.5 Form Field Calendar shows 1970-01-01 instead of empty

Tags: forms, joomla, datepicker, calendar

I'm stucking with this issue:
I use in fomrs the calendar form field, MySQL database field for this is set to DATE and defaults to 0000-00-00
Form field definition in xml uses

```
format="%Y-%m-%d"
default="0000-00-00"
```

On the frontend always appears 1970-01-01 instead of an empty field.
I searched the net but can't found a solution how to get an empty field if there is the zero in database. Can anyoune help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The field for storing this date didn't allow for NULL values, and therefor used 0000-00-00 as default (it's a date field). Thus I decided to see what happened when I changed the field in the database to allow for NULL values and set the value for the specific record to NULL. Et voila... Problem solved. No more "strange date" display.

However... When saving the date-field, Joomla decided that it should be stored as 0000-00-00, making the display bogus again. Therefor I had a look at the model and added the line:

```
if ($data->birth_date == '0000-00-00') { $data->birth_date = ''; }
```

Before returning $data in protected function loadFormData().

Now to finish it off, since the listing still displayed "0000-00-00" I had a look at that model for the listing and added

```
$oneItem->birth_date = ($oneItem->birth_date == '0000-00-00') ? "" : $oneItem->birth_date;
```

before it returned the $items in public function getItems().

Comment: This isn't an answer .. this is a "what I did last summer" monologue that is nearly impossible to wade through.

Answer (score -1):

You have set the default to: 0000-00-00.

This is a time way before computers were invented, php defaults back to the below if the date is invalid or invalid

1970-01-01

Therefore it will default to that as its as far back as it can go.

Set an actual default date or set to NOW to load in  current date.

Comment: Don't think you get the point. I want j3 calendar field to show a empty input if there is no date (null date) in the database. But I find the solution to this: setting database column from DATE to DATETIME and default value to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 solves this issue: jommla shows no an empty input if there is the default value in DB.